# View Empty and Nested Security Groups in Active Directory

Tags: powershell

In my case, some nested groups are also empty but because they are a member of the parent group then that parent group doesn't flag up as empty on my output. I am new to Powershell so any help is appreciated.

I have seen that you can use recursive with `Get-ADGroupMember`, but I'm not sure how to use this with my script because I am using `Get-ADGroup` to search every group in an OU.

```
Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $OU -Filter "GroupCategory -eq 'Security'" -Properties Members | Where-Object {$_.Members.count -eq 0} | Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\test"
```

Is it possible to search the nested groups too?

Comment: Doesn't `Get-ADGroup -filter *` get all groups including nested ?

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`, coupled with calculated properties, to seamlessly reassign the `Name` property values as arguments for the `-Identity` parameters within the `select-object` command, can effectively facilitate the objective.

By engaging with the provided code snippet, you can successfully achieve the desired outcome. Feel free to explore further modifications to align with your requirements.

### PowerShell

```
$ZeroMemberGroups = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $OU -Filter "GroupCategory -eq 'Security'" -Properties Members | Where-Object {
    $_.Members.count -eq 0} | Select-Object Name, 
        @{N="MemberCount";E={$_.Members.count}}, 
        @{N="MemberOfGroups";E={(Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.Name).Name}
        };
##$ZeroMemberGroups;
##$ZeroMemberGroups.MemberOfGroups;
$NestedZeroGroups = $ZeroMemberGroups.MemberOfGroups | ForEach-Object {
    If($_) {Get-ADGroup "$_"  -Properties Members | Where-Object {
        $_.Members.count -eq 0} | Select-Object Name}
        };

($ZeroMemberGroups).Name;
($NestedZeroGroups).Name;
```

---

### Example Output 1

```
Name               MemberCount MemberOfGroups                                                                  
----               ----------- --------------                                                                  
Cool Cat                     0                                                                                 
Rude Cat                     0                                                                                 
Cool Laptops                 0 {Cat Laps, Cat Food}
Cool Rat                     0                                                                                 
Rude Rat                     0                                                                                 
Happy Dog                    0                                                                                 
Sad Dog                      0 Give - Meds                                                                  
Mean Dog                     0                                                                                 
Mean Cat                     0
```

### Example Output 2

```
Cool Cat    
Rude Cat    
Cool Laptops
Cool Rat    
Rude Rat    
Happy Dog   
Sad Dog     
Mean Dog    
Mean Cat    
Cat Laps
Cat Food
Give - Meds
```

## Supporting Resources

- [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adprincipalgroupmembership?view=windowsserver2022-ps)
- [Calculated_Properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1#select-object)
- [Where-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/where-object.html)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)
- [Select-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/select-object.html)

Comment: @JakeSmith This code assumes you want to only see nested groups that also have zero members too. It also assumes the nested groups may not be within the specified OU as defined in my example. Otherwise, I guess it wouldn't be needed as you'd get all those groups. Unless perhaps you want the nested groups of regardless of being type `security` or not. In any case, all trivial for me so happy to help you make further trivial adjustments if needed. Otherwise, Happy lLarning PowerShell Day to you!!